# Branching Process $P[Z_3 > 0]$ where $_3$ is the size of the third generation.

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

In a branching process, suppose $() =  + ^2$
for $0 <  < 1$ and $ +  = 1$.
Assume that the population starts with one ancestor.
Find $[_3 > 0]$ where $_3$ is the size of the third generation.

For this question, I compute that $P(S)=p+qs^{2}$ follows that $s=p+qs^2$. Therefore the probability of extinction is $s=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4pq}}{2q}$ and that the mean progeny is $P'(1)=2q$. However, I honestly don't know how to move from this to find $P[Z_3 > 0]$ where $_3$ is the size of the third generation.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that the probability generating function for $Z_n$ is obtained by $n$-fold composition of the probability generating function of the offspring distribution. So
\begin{align}
P_3(s) &= P(P(P(s)))\\
&= P(P(p+qs^2))\\
&= P(p + q(p+qs^2)^2)\\
&= p+q(p+q(p+qs^2)^2)^2.
\end{align}
Now, 
$$
\mathbb P(Z_3=0) = P_3(0) =  q \left(p^2 q+p\right)^2+p,
$$
so 
$$
\mathbb P(Z_3>0) = 1-\mathbb P(Z_3=0) = 1-(q \left(p^2 q+p\right)^2+p).
$$